# How do I create a jobs queue using AWS DynamoDB and AWS SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda function which I want to trigger at specific intervals, based on jobs parameters. For example, I want to be able to add job params like

```
{"run_at": "2018-06-08-10-10-30", "params": {"metadata":"xyz"}}
```

So i want my lambda function to be triggered at `run_at` time, at that exact minute, with the `params` being passed as event to my lambda function.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can us the DynamoDB's **Time-To-Live** (the timestamp column is set as the TTL) in which the record in the table will be deleted when it expires and the deleted record will appear in **DynamoDB stream**. Once it appear in the stream, you can setup a Lambda to be triggered for further processing (to queue in SQS, publish to SNS, etc). The docs for [Stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) and [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html).

Briefly, you can register a job by adding a record in DynamoDB with a timestamp of when the event should occur (the timestamp is the TTL). Then, once the the timestamp reached, DynamoDB will automatically delete the record and put it into the stream that will trigger a Lambda to start the event.

Take note that all activities (insert/update/delete) on record will be available in the stream. So you may want to do some conditioning logic before in Lambda to only process DELETE record only.

Answer (score 0):

The specific intervals part is easy using [Schedule Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html). You could pass different params into specific Lambda functions using a first Lambda function that then calls a shared function. Other approaches are possible based on what you want to achieve with your design.